# Determine most & least common colour from 2d histogram

Tags: c++, opencv

How can I determine the most common/dominant colour from a 2d histogram? I have produced a 2d histogram from a HSV image. The 2 channels/axis are the Hue and Saturation channels.

Using `minMaxLoc()` on the 2d histogram is providing values but when I draw these values they are both the same colour of red.

[image]

```
/// Using 50 bins for hue and 60 for saturation
int h_bins = 50; int s_bins = 60;
int histSize[] = { h_bins, s_bins };
float h_ranges[] = { 0, 180 };
float s_ranges[] = { 0, 256 };
const float* ranges[] = { h_ranges, s_ranges };
int channels[] = { 0, 1 };

calcHist(&hsv, 1, channels, Mat(), hist, 2, histSize, ranges, true, false);
// not normalising yet as that will affect the min max colour values right?

double min, max;
Point minPnt, maxPnt;
minMaxLoc(hist, &min, &max, &minPnt, &maxPnt);
printf("[%f,%f], [%d,%d], [%d,%d]\n", min, max, minPnt.x, minPnt.y, maxPnt.x, maxPnt.y);
// outputs: [0.000000, 3647.000000], [18, 0], [26, 28]

// Display Min and Max HSV 'colour' to visualise it. Both are red
// Do I need to compensate for the reduction in bins (h=50, s=60)?
Vec3b minHsv(18, 0, 255);
Vec3b maxHsv(26, 28, 255);
Mat minHsvImg(100, 100, CV_8UC3, minHsv);
Mat maxHsvImg(100, 100, CV_8UC3, maxHsv);
cvtColor(minHsvImg, minHsvImg, CV_BGR2HSV);
cvtColor(maxHsvImg, maxHsvImg, CV_BGR2HSV);
rectangle(minHsvImg, { 0, 0, 100, 100 }, minHsv, -1);
rectangle(maxHsvImg, { 0, 0, 100, 100 }, maxHsv, -1);
```

Comment: Although they appear so, they are not the same red. Testing your screenshot on Irfanview, I get 255,28,27 for the top square and 255,0,18 for the bottom one (RGB order).